# ActionMailer not sending emails in local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I've configured my gmail variables in order to send test mails from my app:

#### application.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :domain         => 'mail.google.com',
  :port           => 587,
  :user_name      => 'enriqueisasi@gmail.com',
  :password       => 'mypass',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I can see in my logs its working, but I still don't see the emails in my Gmail:

#### Logs

```
Sent mail to enriqueisasi@gmail.com (219.7ms)
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2016 01:32:55 +0200
From: Your Mailer <hola@benditapizza.es>
To: Me <enriqueisasi@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <57ccaf2742bc0_3d03ff35f488dec6265@MacBook-Pro-de-Enrique-2.local.mail>
Subject: Mensaje de adfadf
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you missed setting this config in `development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

as by default this is on false, preventing mails to be sent from your development environment